# Redirect Logged in user to specific page in wprdpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I want to redirect users after the login to specific page called 'activity'. I have tried the Peter’s Login Redirect plugin but it just worked to the subscriber users although I have added all the roles in the plugin setting.

I have tried to add function to function.php in my theme but I can not find the right one.

Comment: What you write for this ?

Comment: function my_loginredirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
  if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
    if( in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
      return admin_url();
    } else {
      return home_url() . '/avtivity';
    }
  } else {
      return home_url() . '/avtivity';
  }
}
 
add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_loginredirect', 10, 3);

Comment: Please check my answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you for your specific page redirect, you want to do this:

```
function login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
    return home_url('your-page.php');
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

As you used this code...

```
function my_loginredirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) { 
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        if( in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
         return admin_url(); 
        } 
        else { 
            return site_url('avtivity'); 
        } 
} 
add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_loginredirect', 10, 3);
```

Comment: the page "activity" is one of the Buddypress profile pages , I am not sure if it is activity,php

Comment: function login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
    return home_url('www.example.com/activity');
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'login_redirect', 10, 3 );


Is that right to try??

Comment: You did just a wrong thing. change this return site_url('www.example.com/activity');

Comment: Still the same prob 

redirect to the home page

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I still have the same problem

Comment: If you dont mind i can work on that point. Dont worry about payment. I will not take nay charges

Comment: I will do that by FTP if you have ?